# Как создать bind в kivy python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, kivy

Хочу создать бинд к кнопке,в tkinter это `x.bind('<Button-1>',func)`,подскажите как сделать это в kivy

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core window import Window


class KivyApkBuilder(App):

    def __init__(self, **kvargs):
        super(KivyApkBuilder, self).__init__(**kvargs)
    Window.bind(on_keyboard=self.events_program)

    def events_program(self, instance, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
            if keyboard  == scancode:
                ...
```

Сканкоды событий, думаю, сами найдете.

Comment: я имею ввиду назначить кнопку

Comment: @QqqqSsss: вы похоже забываете слов "мыши". Вы хотите вызвать функцию по нажатию на кнопку [мыши], но необязательно что над кнопкой [GUI элементом] (почему?)

Comment: Изменил ответ, согласно вашему вопросу.